# How to fix grant_type error is NULL - unsupported grant type with Pay Pal's REST API for access token

Tags: node.js, paypal, access-token, paypal-rest-sdk, superagent

I'm calling Paypal's REST API to get an access token https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

I'm using node with [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) to make the AJAX call.

Here is my code:

```
const basicAuth = Buffer.from(`${PAYPAL_CLIENT}:${PAYPAL_SECRET}`).toString('base64')

request
  .post(PAYPAL_OAUTH_API)
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
  .set('Authorization', `Basic ${basicAuth}`)
  .send()
  .end((result) => {
    console.log(result.response.error)
  })
```

And here is the logs with the errors I'm getting

```
{ Error: cannot POST /v1/oauth2/token/ (400)
    at Response.toError (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:94:15)
    at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\response-base.js:123:16)
    at new Response (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:41:8)
    at Request._emitResponse (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:850:20)
    at parser (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1036:38)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\parsers\json.js:19:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  status: 400,
  text: '{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Grant Type is NULL"}',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v1/oauth2/token/' }
```

Why am I getting an error unssuported grant type - the grant type is NULL?
In postman it works but I can't get it to work with superagent and node. Paypal gives two examples [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) with postman and curl. Why is it not working with superagent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From paypal docs which you've linked to:

> If you use a command-line tool other than cURL, set the `Accept header` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

From `superget` docs which you've linked to:

> By default sending strings will set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

So change your request to:

```
// PAYPAL_LINK = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"
// PAYPAL_OAUTH_API = "/v1/oauth2/token"
request(PAYPAL_LINK)
  .post(PAYPAL_OAUTH_API)
  .send('grant_type=client_credentials')
  .auth(PAYPAL_CLIENT, PAYPAL_SECRET)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Optionally set `Accept: application/json` if you want response as `json`

Comment: I tried that and the result object that is passed through at the end is NULL. No response whatsoever. Strange

Comment: updated answer (was checking the wrong property).Also added error handler to check for errors check now

Comment: The result is still NULL. Here are the logs
`
C:\Users\shlomo\projects\tribewise-backend-v1\app\controllers\miscellaneous.js:140
  console.log(result.body);
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
    at C:/Users/shlomo/projects/tribewise-backend-v1/app/controllers/miscellaneous.js:123:24

`

Comment: updated answer, try replacing your `Authorization` headers

Comment: Result is still NULL

Comment: made some changes, looks like base and endpoint needs to be passed saperately. Made faux request to `sandbox` endpoint, got error `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}` and `on('error')` event and `result` is null.

Comment: I figured it out. It's showing null because I'm using the .end() promise incorrectly. The .end() promise according to superagent docs returns 2 values: .end(err, res). The first value is null because there is no error with the code. I shouldn't be using the old callback style  .end(). I should be using .then() and .catch(). If .end() is used then the second param passed in is the response value. 
Your answer was indeed correct! It needed to be formatted to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That solved the grant_type issue.
Please update your answer to reflect this. 
Thank you!